# How do I lower the default bound of an array from 1 to 0?

Tags: loops, fortran

```
     implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
     real*8 x,y(11)

     do i=0,10
       x=0.35139534352933061.D0
       y=1.D0/x*(cosh(x/2.D0*(2.D0*i-a))-cosh(x*a/2.D0))
       write(*,*) i,y(i)
     end do
```

Hello, I'm trying to print the values of my function,`y`,
so my program should print `y(0),y(1),y(2)...y(10)`. But since in Fortran, the first element is `y(1)` instead of `y(0)`, Fortran treats `y(0)` as a big number in stead of the first element. How can I get the result of `y` when `i=0`?

My first try is:

```
     implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
     real*8 x,y(11)

     do i=0,10
       x=0.35139534352933061.D0
       y=1.D0/x*(cosh(x/2.D0*(2.D0*i-a))-cosh(x*a/2.D0))
       y0=1.D0/x*(cosh(x/2.D0*(-a))-cosh(x*a/2.D0))
       y(0)=y0
       write(*,*) i,y(i)
     end do
```

But I get the following warning:

> Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (0 < 1) in dimension 1

My workaround for the problem:

```
do i=1,11
     y=1.D0/x*(cosh(x/2.D0*(2.D0*(i-1)-a))-cosh(x*a/2.D0))
     write(10,*) i,y(i)
   end do
```

I just changed the argument `(i)` with `(i-1)` and `i=0,10` with `i=1,11`

Comment: declare as `real y(0:10)`.  By the way your `y=` assignment is assigning to the entire array.

Comment: Thank you,that was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do any `implicit` other than `implicit none`. It is far too easy to create hard to debug bugs by simple typos when you use implicit types.

You can declare arrays with custom bounds by declaring them directly:

```
real :: x(0:10)
real, dimension(-5:5, 2:17) :: y
```

Note though that the array bounds will not persist through procedure calls:

```
module test_bounds

    implicit none

contains
    subroutine print_a(a)
        integer, intent(in) :: a(:)
        print*, 'w/o passed bounds:'
        print*, 'lbound(a) : ', lbound(a, 1)
        print*, 'ubound(a) : ', ubound(a, 1)
    end subroutine print_a

    subroutine print_a_bounds(a, start)
        integer, intent(in) :: start
        integer, intent(in) :: a(start:)
        print*, 'w passed bounds:'
        print*, 'lbound(a) : ', lbound(a, 1)
        print*, 'ubound(a) : ', ubound(a, 1)
    end subroutine print_a_bounds
end module test_bounds


program bounds
    use test_bounds
    implicit none
    integer :: a(0:10)
    integer :: i

    a = (/ (i, i=0, 10) /)

    print*, 'in main:'
    print*, 'lbound(a) : ', lbound(a, 1)
    print*, 'ubound(a) : ', ubound(a, 1)


    call print_a(a)
    call print_a_bounds(a, start=lbound(a, 1))

end program bounds
```

Output:

```
 in main:
 lbound(a) :            0
 ubound(a) :           10
 w/o passed bounds:
 lbound(a) :            1
 ubound(a) :           11
 w passed bounds:
 lbound(a) :            0
 ubound(a) :           10
```

Comment: one thing that regularly vexes me if the array bounds and when they are passed and when they are not. When I have REAL, DIMENSION(:), intent :: A  then it seems to work. It is germane as I have an interpolation and allocate the array(0:(n+1))... Or is a nuance of allocatable?

Comment: I'm not aware of this ever working. I'm fairly sure that you need to explicitly declare the bounds in every new scope if they start somewhere other than `1`.

Comment: Maybe that is why it is "ever vexing"?  I am using ifort 2013 So I will check it, but I was using LBOUND and UBOUND and it was correct.